# How sockets relate to common networking APIs

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

This morning I asked a sockets-related question, but this is a different beast and so I decided making a separate post altogether.

I now have a good idea of what sockets are, and the purpose(s) they serve. I'm trying to understand their relation to Java NIO, Java RMI, and so-called networking APIs like Netty or MINA.

1. Are sockets the basis of all Java-based networking, and is NIO the foundation of Java-based networking (i.e., is it the API that provides the socket structures for *higher* frameworks like Netty or MINA)?  If not, then what is the foundation of Java's networking capabilities?
2. Can one use sockets (which as I understand it, or network-layer constructs), to send (byte-wise) messages compliant with higher protocols, such as TCP or UDP, HTTP, FTP, etc? If so, I would imagine that development teams might, for example, make their own HttpProtocol library, or SSLProtocol library, yes?
3. My understanding is that NIO is the basis of all Java networking, and that RMI, Netty, MINA, etc. all extend the NIO framework into their own implementations. Is this correct? If not, how do these frameworks relate to each other?

Thanks again for all your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are sockets the basis of all Java-based networking,

For IP protocols, yes. There might be special libraries such as [JavaComm](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141752.html) for serial port communication, and [JAIN](http://java.sun.com/products/jain/) for various telecom protocols that's not socket based

> and is NIO the foundation of Java-based networking

Not really, sockets are. see the previous answer. NIO builds on and augments sockets though, as well as other things. The most important part is probably that NIO allows you to listen for events on several sockets in a single thread and do non-blocking IO. Netty and Mina takes advantage of the NIO apis.

NIO stands for New I/O, and was a new API for doing IO introduced in Java 1.4. It does a lot of other stuff than socket IO though. Arguably, NIO will allow you to do socket IO more efficently at the cost of more complexity.

> Can one use sockets (which as I understand it, or network-layer constructs), to send (byte-wise) messages compliant with higher protocols, such as TCP or UDP,

No. Sockets gives you access to transport protocols such as TCP or UDP (actually with Java it's only TCP and UDP, in the future, probably SCTP as well). You can build stuff that works on top of TCP/UDP, not implement TCP/UDP yourself(unless you want to implement an IP stack on top of TCP or UDP - which is what several VPN or tunelling protocols does)

> HTTP, FTP, etc?

Yes, these commonly work on top of TCP, you can implement HTTP, FTP and other protocols that that runs above TCP/UDP by using sockets in java - that's what sockets are for.

Comment: nos - thank you for the excellent answer. One question though: if sockets are the basis of Java networking, then where do they come from? They must be external to Java, perhaps provided by the OS?

Comment: sure, files/sockets are provided by the OS.

Comment: Are sockets not serial port-based? What's different than a socket and this JavaComm or JAIN? Wouldn't they all, at some basic level, bind to a port and listen for I/O?

Comment: "Serial Port" sounds like a generic term, but in this context it means "async serial port, probably RS-232".  Sockets are TCP/IP or UPD/IP and are most commonly Ethernet based.  At least for the LAN.

Comment: @Pam Sockets are pretty specific, they generally refer to a specific style of API(namely BSD Sockets http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets). That style of interfacing to some form of network communication  has been carried through to most operating systems and programming languages. A native C socket API might give you access to a whole range of low level protocols, mostly TCP/IP based, but also others, e.g. bluetooth, appletalk, X.25 etc, but even the native APIs have exceptions, e.g. serial programming. In java , sockets are for IP/UDP and IP/TCP only.

Answer (score 0):

Sockets are the Java basic building blocks for networking. They only allow you to do basic operations: opening a connection (TCP or UDP), writing or reading bytes and closing the connection. They also handle failure cases by throwing exceptions. In the OSI model, this is the 4th layer (transport).

Higher level APIs are built on top of sockets, they allow to do more interesting tasks such as HTTP connections or SSL communication.

Java NIO is the new version of the first Java IO API. As far as networking is concerned it essentially brings a new API for non blocking sockets.

Higher level APIs are built on top of Java IO and/or Java NIO.

Comment: Thanks Guillaume! So, just to clarify: Java NIO/IO are the standard Java sockets frameworks, and other frameworks like Netty or MINA build upon that framework by providing implementations of higher-layer protocols, yes? Does the same apply for Java RMI (does RMI extend NIO like Netty/MINA?). Thanks!

Comment: Right, Java NIO/IO implement sockets while other libraries implement higher level protocols on top of these sockets. RMI is a package for communicating with remote objects. RMI uses URL protocols so most of the time it will use sockets for communication.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I'm confused with RMI because I'm seeing APIs like NIO, Netty, MINA, etc. that are all sockets-based and which implement specific protocols... what protocols does RMI implement and how does this differ than normal client/server communication using, say, Netty?

Comment: RMI provides the wiring for calling methods on objects located on a remote server. You could look at it like a protocol on the same level as HTTP, SOAP, JMS...

Comment: Guillaume, last question! So is it fair to summarize that RMI is an RPC framework that heavily uses sockets (and perhaps other non-sockets technologies) to serialize objects between client and server, and because the communication is between 2 programs (the client and the server), then this serialized transmission could be viewed as an "application layer" protocol? Thanks again for all your help so far!

Comment: RMI doesn't use URL protocols, whatever they are.